# Using "when" and "at that time" at the same time

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, time

A conjunction "when" and a phrase "at that time" seem to have similar meanings because both indicate time.

Can I use both of them in one sentence like this:

> What did you mean when you said "We are more than people," at that time?

Comment: Are you Korean, or asking about Korean learners of English?

Comment: @gotube  Well, I am not Korean, but, from Asia.  Was it like Korean language?

Comment: Yes, Koreans famously overuse "at that time" when speaking English because it's the direct translation of a Korean phrase that they use constantly in Korean. In English, there is no equivalent.

Comment: @gotube Oh, I see!  I didn't know that.  So, I don't need to use "at that time" every time.  Thank you!

Comment: Probably not. See my answer below.

Comment: @gotube Oh, I understand!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, it's best to put like:

> At that time, what did you mean when you said "we are more than people"?

Or even simpler put:

> What did you mean when you said "we are more than people"?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is not to use two or more time expressions to describe the same moment.

In your example, '*at that time*' and '*when you said "We are more than people,"*' are the exact same thing, so it's redundant and incorrect. It's like saying "at that time, at that time".